# How should I represent inheritance+polymorphism with DTOs, when working with GraphQL?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, graphql

I have a domain layer where I have models such as an abstract class `User` that is implemented by concrete classes `Client` and `Seller`, where `User` holds some common data and functionality but each of the concrete classes have their unique ones too.

Now I could see a simple mapping strategy being used for example,

`User` -> `UserDto`

`Client` -> `ClientDto`

`Seller` -> `SellerDto`

Where `UserDto` only contains the fields declared in `User`, `ClientDto` only contains fields unique to `Client`, etc.

However, I run into an issue when pairing this with a GraphQL resolver. If I have the following schema:

```
type Query {
    getUser(id: ID!): User
}

interface User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
}

type Client implements User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    name: String!
}

type Seller implements User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    brand: String!
}
```

And lets say I run the following query:

```
query {
    getUser("A1B2C3") {
        id
        email
        ... on Client {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

If I were to return from, say, a `UserService.getUser(String id)` an object of type `UserDTO`, then it would not have the necessary information to respond adequately to the GraphQL request, even though the corresponding `User` object DID have that needed information, as it was in fact an instance of one of the concrete classes. How do I prevent this data loss from taking place, and represent polymorphic/inheritance-based entities effectively with DTOs?